# Runtime synchronization failed

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

After starting one server in a cluster we are getting below error while other node is working fine

Runtime synchronization failed (No constructor has a @ConstructorProperties for this set of items: [action, createdTime, downloadLink, message, multiLanguageMessagesJSON])

Server MobileFirst 7.1

Please advice ?

Comment: Have you resolved this? It sounds like your deployment in the cluster is... not good. You should most likely remove this question and open a PMR instead... it's not so related to programming.

Answer (score 0):

Such an error may happen because the faulty server may be missing the correct level of an iFix, unlike the rest of the servers in the cluster, or an iFix that was "partially" installed, i.e. it is missing the correct JEE .jar or the admin .war files.